# getting unhandled exception error when trying to have access to the detected object values using opencv / c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to have access to all values in the detected object. this is what I have done until now ..

```
int width;
int height;
cv::Mat dis = Mat(width, height, CV_8UC1,Dis);
cv::Mat cannyEdge(dis.rows, dis.cols, CV_32FC1);
GaussianBlur( dis, dis, Size(3, 3), 2, 2 );
Canny( dis, cannyEdge , 100 , 100 * 3, 3);
imshow("canny_edge",cannyEdge);
}
findContours(cannyEdge, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

Mat raw_dist( dis.size(), CV_32FC1 );

    for( int j = 0; j < dis.rows; j++ ){
         for( int i = 0; i < dis.cols; i++ ){ 
             raw_dist.at<float>(j,i) = pointPolygonTest( contours[0], Point2f(i,j), true );
         }
    }
```

I get Unhandled exception error in this line:

```
 raw_dist.at<float>(j,i) = pointPolygonTest( contours[0], Point2f(i,j), true );
```

anybody knows what is the problem?

Comment: What is `contours` and does it have at least one thing in it?

Comment: are you familiar with opencv?

Comment: you are right..I checked findcontours line..seems empty!